# NodeJS Raspberry Pi & rpio Watch button not working

Tags: node.js

I've installed the rpio node module, the first time I ran it, I changed the pin to 33. It worked, and outputted some info and changed upon changing the state of the button. However, after stopping the script, then running it again it doesn't seem to work. I've tried a reboot and thats still given me no luck.

Here is my code:

```js
var rpio = require('rpio');

var pin = 33;
console.log('test');

rpio.open(pin, rpio.INPUT, rpio.PULL_DOWN);


function pollcb(cbpin)
{

 var state = rpio.read(cbpin) ? 'pressed' : 'released';
 console.log('Button event on P%d (button currently %s)', cbpin, state);

}

rpio.poll(pin, pollcb);
```

Comment: To what other pin is the button connected?

Comment: The ground pin .

Comment: Aah, swapped the wire to the 3v pin, and it seems to be working now. Strange that it worked once with the ground pin :s

Comment: You probably need a resistor between the switch and the 3V! FWIW: the "pull down" argument means that the default of the input will be low (0v), so the opposite (when the button is pressed) should be high (3.3v/5v).